# MySQL Simple Query Error

Tags: java, mysql, insert-update

I am new to MySQL and I wrote a simple query bellow:

```
CREATE Table tblFeedBack
(
    `FeedBackID` INT AUTO_IncremeNT,
    `UserID` INT,
    `Inserted_TS` TIMESTAMP ,
    `FeedBackValue` VARCHAR(100),
     PRIMARY KEY (FeedBackID)
);

CREATE PROCEDURE tblFeedBack_InsertUpdate
(
    IN U_ID INT,
    IN FB_Value VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN    
    IF ((Select COUNT(*) From 'tblFeedback') < 3)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO 'tblFeedBack' (`UserID`,`FeedBackValue`) 
            VALUES (U_ID,FB_Value);
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @MostRecentFID INT;

            SELECT TOP 1 `FeedBackID` FROM tblFeedback 
            WHERE UID = U_ID
            ORDER BY `Inserted_TS` DESC
            INTO @MostRecentFID;

            UPDATE tblfeedback
            SET `FeedBackValue` = @FeedBackValue
            WHERE `FeedBackID` = @MostRecentFID 
        END
END
```

I am getting this error:

```
 Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tblFeedBack' (`UserID`,`FeedBackValue`) VALUES (1,'12')' at line 9
```

Can anyone please help me solve this one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Among other things, you are mixing syntax from SQL Server into your code.  MySQL does not support `top`, for instance.

Comment: yes.actually i am learning mysql and knows much about sql so it happens.but now even with all those corrections it's not working with some weird error. Unknown Error Occurred: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not support `TOP` you want to use `LIMIT 1` instead as they are ordered.

```
Select `FeedBackID` FROM tblFeedback 
WHERE UID = U_ID
ORDER BY `Inserted_TS` DESC
LIMIT 1
INTO @MostRecentFID;
```

Also, when you query a table using quotes it becomes case sensitive.

```
IF ((Select COUNT(*) From 'tblFeedback') < 3)
```

Should be

```
IF ((Select COUNT(*) From 'tblFeedBack') < 3)
```

Fix these 2 errors and it should work.

Comment: @user3728789 try replacing the single quotes with backtick.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE tblFeedBack_InsertUpdate
(
IN U_ID INT,
IN FB_Value VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN

 declare @cnt int;
Select COUNT(*) From 'tblFeedback' into @cnt
IF ((@cnt < 3)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tblfeedback (`UserID`,`FeedBackValue`) VALUES (U_ID,FB_Value);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
DECLARE @MostRecentFID INT;

Select  `FeedBackID` FROM tblfeedback 
WHERE UserID = U_ID
ORDER BY `Inserted_TS` DESC
LIMIT 1
INTO @MostRecentFID;

UPDATE tblfeedback
SET `FeedBackValue` = @FeedBackValue
Where `FeedBackID` = @MostRecentFID 
END
END

Comment: This is what I had made update,But still getting err.can you please help me further with this ?

Comment: Unknown Error Occurred: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity....I am using WAMP server and my simple insert/update queries are working on the same table .

Comment: Is it WAMP server related issue ?

Comment: @user3728789 have you modified any xml files in your wamp configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

The table names are different in the insert query. One contains 'tblFeed**b**ack' and other contains 'tblFeed**B**ack'

Also, please try to remove single quotes near table names in the query.